# Drag Drop, get filename and last 23 characters

Tags: c#

I want to get the filename and last 23 characters when I drag into a textbox.

I have it working, but I would like to just have one line.  Currently, I think I am doing a bit of a workaround. As I must use a string array, and I only want one string, so I don't really need an array.

```
private void First_DragDrop(object sender, DragEventArgs e)
{
    string[] fileList = e.Data.GetData(DataFormats.FileDrop) as string[];
    string filename = Path.GetFileNameWithoutExtension(fileList[0]);
    First.Text = filename.Substring(filename.Length - 23, 23);
}
```

As you can see, I must do it in 3 steps. First, get the string array.  Then, get one string from that array and turn it into a filename.  FInally, I need to get the last 23 characters of that string.

I think I should be able to just get everything immediately. Though maybe it's not possible?  It just seems weird that I must use an array that contains one thing.

Comment: Thanks as always Jamal, much appreciated for the corrections:)

Comment: You're welcome. :-) Just want to help others help you.

Answer (score 3):

Yes, you can write everything in one line, but you will not be happy with the result. And no, .Net creators did not think of implementing a single call which would return exactly 23 characters of dropped file name. :) Silly them. :)

Meanwhile, your code makes sense. I see only two possible issues:

1. You do not handle multiple files being dropped (that is why there is an array)
2. You do not handle `fileList` being `null`.

Comment: Hehe, well to bad;P But the problem is, as you say, i have an array for multiple (i never drop multiple files), and which is why i want to only get the file dropped (if i drop more files, just ignore them or something), cause i am only interested in 1 file, it doesn´t make sense to get that info from many files at the same time.

Comment: @Zerowalker, if you develop application for yourself - then its fine, i guess. If not, then you should not assume that user will only drop single file. You should not even assume that he will drop files, and not something else.

Comment: it´s for myself, so it shouldn´t be a problem:)

Comment: But is there a way to simple put it into a single string? or am i forced to use an array?

Comment: @Zerowalker, you have to use an array

Comment: Ah okay, good to know, have been searching on it. Thanks!